# What the most efficient way to monitor really large directories on FreeBSD

Tags: linux, freebsd, inotify, kqueue

I have a FreeBSD installation and a very large directory structure with 10TiB of small files.

I want to programmatically monitor and handle events such as a new file created or existing modified.
I have tried to use `kqueue()` but it requires to open every directory and file. Traversing through the whole directory structure is taking too long and can never be finished in adequate time. (I even left it for a night and had no success.)

Is there another way to do the same on FreeBSD but in an efficient way?

By the way, does Linux handle such amount of data using inotify?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Could this [question/answers](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40705/monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-run-a-command-when-a-change-is-detected) be a solution for your situation? Launchd is ported to FreeBSD.

Comment: got any feasible solution for watching big directory?

Comment: @amarjeetAnand Unfortunately, no. We opted for a simple spool design and scheduled monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at /usr/ports/devel/fam, the File Alteration Monitor, which provides an API which applications can use to be notified when specific files or directories are changed.